# How to make a field READONLY in lift crudify

Tags: scala, lift

I have a field that I would like to be read-only and have a default value.

here what I have till now:

```
    object passwd extends MappedString(this, 20) 
    {
       override def defaultValue = "XXX" + Random.alphanumeric.take(12).mkString // some default value
//  readOnly = true // Or something similar??? 
    }
```

I tried overriding toHtml, asHtml, toForm, displayHtml but they all change the view or the label or something else.

I just want the defaultValue to be automatically generated (which works) but the users not to be able to edit that field when create/editing the entity.

Any advice would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it,

Just override _toForm  and disable the input element:

```
import net.liftweb.http.S

override def _toForm =  
    S.fmapFunc({s: List[String] => this.setFromAny(s)}){name =>  
    Full(<input disabled='disabled' type='text' id={fieldId} maxlength={maxLen.toString}  
    name={name}  
    value={is match {case null => "" case s => s.toString}}/>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trait `MappedField` defines the methods `writePermission_?` and `readPermission_?`:

```
/**
 * Given the current execution state, can the field be written?
 */
def writePermission_? = false
/**
 * Given the current execution state, can the field be read?
 */
def readPermission_? = false
```

So you could just override these with

```
object passwd extends MappedString(this, 20) {
  override def defaultValue = "XXX" + Random.alphanumeric.take(12).mkString // some default value
  override writePermission_? = false
  override readPermission_? = true
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: that's not exactly what I need.
The field must show up, but must be not editable, that is, the textbox must contain the default value, but must be disabled so users can't change it.

Comment: Should `override writePermission_? = false` and `override readPermission_? = true` instead be `override def writePermission_? = false` and `override def readPermission_? = true`? This is what worked for me.